# Why is htop producing different reports than Activity Monitor?

Tags: macos, activity-monitor, monitoring

I'm using htop on my Mac. I put it side by side with Activity Monitor, but the reports are widely different.

On Activity Monitor, I can get finder using up to 100% of CPU, while it doesn't show at all the process on htop. Is there a better tool for monitoring processes for Yosemite?

Comment: Are you root when you run htop?

Comment: No, I'm a user in the sudo group

Comment: Than run 'sudo htop' and you will have task CPU usage and cumulative time.

Comment: Makes sense. Do you want add it as an answer? I'll mark as it as such.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In order to get accurate processes, cpu usage and accumulative time, the user running `htop` should be root. This is not the case with `top`, because it has the "set-user-ID-on-execution bit" (suid) set.

Execute `sudo htop` from your user terminal or if you trust your local users add the suid to the binary (`# chmod u+s path-to-htop-binary`).

Comment: Thank you, it's been a problem for months now and I've been blaming the htop for missing out processes with high CPU usage (and apparently different uid's).